# Are there any formal grammars describing the set of all directed graphs?

Tags: graphs, context-free, formal-grammars

Let `GRAPHS` be the set of all directed graphs.

Is  there a set of strings `STRYNGS` such that there exists a bijection between
`GRAPHS` and `STRYNGS`?

The canonical definition of directed graph comes to mind:
An ordered pair of two sets, (V, E) such that V is a set of vertices
and E is a set of ordered pairs of elements in V.

Perhaps the following string is in the set of strings:

```
(  {0, 1, 2} ,    {(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0)}   )
```

Maybe we can use Zermelo's definition of natural number:

```
1 = { }     
2 = {{ }}      
3 = {{{ }}} 
and so on...
```

The following two graphs are isomorphic:

```
(  {0, 1, 2} ,    {(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0)}   )
(  {9, 5, 3} ,    {(9, 5), (5, 9), (5, 3), (3, 9)}   )
```

`STRYNGS` need not contain *all graphs* per se, but merely at least one representative from each equivalence class defined by the graph isomorphism  relation.

If there there exists such set of strings `STRYNGS`, and there exists a bijection between the strings and the set of digraphs `GRAPHS`, does there also exist a grammar describing `STRYNGS`?

The grammar can be Context-sensitive, context-free or otherwise; any kind of grammar will do.

Comment: Just in case you have not noticed, [unrestricted grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrestricted_grammar#Equivalence_to_Turing_machines) is equivalent to Turing machines.

Comment: With respect to the above comment, I recommend that you update your question to "does there exist a context-sensitive grammar that describes `STRYNGS`?".